# google map Gmapfp Plugin Joomla

Tags: joomla

The plugin is inserted this way -

```
 {gmapfp id="1" zmap="10" wiki="2" hmap="700"}
```

Now, if i was getting the id number from the url or from the cookie, then how do i set it dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, the module/plugin takes the string before any output to the frontend also it is hard coded in the article and you can't change it dynamically on the front-end. The only way to do it is to edit the plugin to take the id from the URL/Cookie if you give me some code I can explain.